# How to Set the gas limit for the Genesis.json in a Private chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

I want to know on what  basis the gas limit is set I have some of the contracts to be implemented in a private which for which i used a genesis block with gas limit 2100000 , but while deploying the contract using truffle it showed me gas limit exceeds

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set the gas limit. I was not having this problem in testrpc, but was having this in the actual Ethereum test chain.

1_initial_migration.js

```js
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations, {gas: 155000});
};
```